# How to use beautifulsoup to parse a HTML tag with multiple attributes in class?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to parse this line, but it's not picking it up.

This is my code:

```
symbols = bsObj.findAll("span", {"class":{"qb_up", "qb_down", re.compile('* qb_shad')}})
```

This is the HTML code I'm trying to pick up:

```
<td align="right" class="ds_weighted_alpha qb_shad" nowrap="nowrap">0.00</td>
```

Comment: you need `td`, why you `find('span')`

Answer (score 0):

```
> import bs4 
> import re
> 
> td_page = '<td align="right" class="ds_weighted_alpha qb_shad"
> nowrap="nowrap">0.00</td>'
> 
> bsObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(td_page, "lxml")
> 
> symbols = bsObj.find("td", class_=re.compile("ds_weighted"))
> 
> symbols_get = symbols.get("class")
In [107]: symbols_get
Out[116]: 
['ds_weighted_alpha', 'qb_shad']
```

Don't worry about attributes being seperated. Just pass the relevant tag to `get` method and if there are multiple values in the attribute, it will give you a list. As it is suggested by @宏杰李 you should call the `find` method on the `td` tag not on `span`, if you are indeed dealing with the provided code